# Why isn't my valve controller not providing sufficient amount of voltage to my fan?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, valves, power-transmission

We're using the valve controller below to control the speed of a (generic) fan: https://products.axiomatic.com/viewitems/valve-controls/can-to-4-outputs-valve-controller

Problem: We're supplying the controller with a 24 Vdc (it uses CAN protocol) and we want to send out a 0-5 Vdc to control the speed of the fan.

The fan is supplied by a 24Vdc signal but we noticed that the 0-5 Vdc signal from the controller goes to high impedance (1Mohm!) input only when we try to control the speed. And the voltage in the fan only ends up measuring half (2.5v), so it doesn't reach its max speed.

I have been thinking about this for hours without a solution, when we connect the fan to a 5Vdc power supply, it works well and gets to its max speed. I also checked the CAN high and CAN low of the Valve controller and terminal resistance is ok, any other suggestion from experts would be extremely appreciated as to why the impedance from the controller rises so much

Comment: Check that controller output at open circuit.  If it produces 5V that then drops to half with the connection in place, then you just need more current- Consider a buffer. If it is 3V at open, then that's just your controller- Consider an amp.

Comment: maybe because a control signal isn't intended to run a fan?